# Assign the returned value of a function to a variable‎ in unix shell script

Tags: function, shell, unix

I tried to print the value returned from testfunction. But it is not displaying anything . I used `./filename.sh` to execute the script. Please help

```
#!/bin/ksh
testfunction()
{

k=5

return $k

}

val=$(testfunction)

echo  $val
```

Answer (score 36):

The value returned by the function is stored in `$?`, and is not captured by `$()`.

In other words:

```
testFunction() 
{ 
    k=5
    echo 3
    return $k 
}

val=$(testFunction)
echo $? # prints 5
echo $val  # prints 3
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do will capture the last value 'echoed' in your function in val variable

```php
val=$(testFunction)
```

If you want to capture return value of your function then you should utilize $? [i.e. echo $?] which is last exit status.

Answer (score -3):

This ksh functions works:

```
IPADDRESS()     # get the IP address of this host
{
    # purpose: to get the IP address of this host
    #       and return it as a character string
    #
    typeset -l IPADDR
    IPADDR=$(ifconfig -a | grep inet | grep -v '127.0.0.1' | awk '{print $2}')
    print $IPADDR
}

IP_Address=$(IPADDRESS)
echo $IP_Address
exit
```